# "В несезон бар не работает" - как быть с несезоном?

Tags: слитно-раздельно

> ЛАЗУРНЫЙ БЕРЕГ В «НЕ СЕЗОН» ОБЛАДАЕТ ОСОБЫМ ШАРМОМ: НЕТ ТОЛП ТУРИСТОВ,
>   СОЗДАЮЩИХ МНОГОЧАСОВЫЕ ПРОБКИ, НЕТ ЗАОБЛАЧНЫХ ЦЕН. КРОМЕ ТОГО, ВПЛОТЬ
>   ДО МАЯ ОТСЮДА МОЖНО МАХНУТЬ В ГОРЫ, КОТОРЫЕ ВСЕГО В ЧАСЕ ЕЗДЫ ОТ
>   ПОБЕРЕЖЬЯ.
>
> В не сезон это место обладает волшебным магнетизмом, зимой ты здесь не
>   пришлый «чужак», а скорее местный.

**[5 ПРИЧИН ДЛЯ НИЦЦЫ В НЕ СЕЗОН](https://www.euromag.ru/france/46695.html)**

---

Других пристойных прецедентов я не нашла... Раздельно и кавычки? Или как?

Автор хочет слитно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Практически используются обе формы.**

**В словаре слова "несезон" нет,** и перспективы туда попасть у него туманные, так как используется только одна падежная форма с предлогом В.

**С другой стороны, в "не сезон" приходится писать в кавычках,** так как предлог В относится к сочетанию "не сезон", а вот кавычки для общеизвестного термина вроде бы уже лишние.

**Чтобы слово "несезон" закрепилось в языке,** ему надо "набрать" частотность употребления, пока же оно еще очень непривычно выглядит на письме.

**Примеры:**

Мы приехали в Сен-Жан-де-Люз **в «не сезон»,** и городок был пустынным. [Леонид Утесов. «Спасибо, сердце!» (1982)

Уже в конце ноября, после возвращения из Польши, я попал **в «не сезон»** на две недели в Репино, в Дом творчества композиторов. [Александр Городницкий. «И жить еще надежде» (2001)]

Answer (score 2):

*— Что-то жареные каштаны не продают.*

*— Не сезон нынче...*

Но:

*Лазурный Берег в несезон обладает особым шармом...*

С предлогом я бы писал слитно. И даже: *"У несезона свой шарм"*. Конечно, это сравнительно новый неологизм, но подобная тенденция, однако, существует. Ничего не попишешь!

Comment: Не то чтобы это неологизм, но похоже на "непогода". В непогоду. В несезон.

Answer (score 2):

"Несезон" здесь самостоятельное понятие, не являющееся отрицанием. Поэтому слитно.

> 2. Пишутся слитно с не существительные, которые в сочетании с не
>      приобретают противоположное значение; обычно такие слова можно 
>      заменить синонимами без не, например: неправда (ср.: ложь), неприятель
>      (ср.: враг), несчастье (ср.: беда).

Розенталь.
http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/38.htm

Answer (score 2):

Разговорному неологизму "в несезон" следовало бы предпочесть:"в межсезонье" или "в мертвый сезон". Это  устоявшиеся, пригодные для письма, формы.