# "Бюджетно исполнить поездку по культурным достопримечательностям" - так можно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

"Бюджетно исполнить поездку по культурным достопримечательностям" - так можно? Пусть ёрничество, но - грамотное?

> В августе стоят высокие температуры, потому конец лета считается
>   «не-сезоном», а значит, поездку по культурным достопримечательностям
>   можно очень бюджетно исполнить. Это на побережье дорого и людно, а вот
>   в городах наоборот – дёшево и пусто… Правда, сердито. В смысле – тяжело.

"Бюджетно" подразумевает *малюбюджетно*?

А *некультурные* достопримечательности - это что? очаги вандализма (к примеру)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

По поводу "несезона" напоминаю, что был Ваш же вопрос [*“В несезон бар не работает” - как быть с несезоном?*](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/432048/%D0%92-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC). Там предлагалось писать слитно, допускалось раздельно, но не было  дефиса. Да и в Нацкорпусе варианта с дефисом я не нашел.

Культурные достопримечательности связаны с культурой.

БЮДЖЕТНЫЙ  — предназначенный для лиц с ограниченным достатком. Б. автомобиль. Б-ое жильё. Б-ая ценовая категория товаров. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B1%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9))

"Бюджетно исполнить" мне кажется  приемлемым, именно в связи с ассоциацией с исполнением бюджета, в данном случае — о скромном семейном бюджете.

Запятая после *значит* кажется мне лишней:

> Союз значит (то же, что «и поэтому, следовательно») соединяет простые предложения в составе сложного. Запятая ставится перед союзом: Тучи собираются, значит будет дождь. Ты сердишься, значит ты не прав. ([Ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9A+%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83+243879))

Comment: По поводу запятой после "значит" Справка ошиблась: *«Юпитер, ты сердишься — значит, ты не прав»*. В значении *следовательно.* А "несезон" был для другой публикации; эта - для АСТа, там будет своя корректура. Посмотрим потом.

Comment: "...Практика письма показывает, что слово *значит* обычно выделяется знаками препинания почти во всех своих синтаксических функциях (кроме функции сказуемого). Кроме того, во многих случаях возможны варианты пунктуации в одном и том же предложении. Ср. одинаково возможные: *Ревнует, значит (=и следовательно) любит; Ревнует – значит (=это) любит*. В спорных случаях окончательное решение о расстановке знаков препинания принимает автор текста".

Answer (score 2):

**В августе температуры держатся высокие,** потому конец лета считается **несезоном**, а значит поездку по культурным достопримечательностям можно очень бюджетно **"исполнить"**. Это на побережье дорого и людно, а вот в городах наоборот – дёшево и пусто… Правда, сердито. В смысле – тяжело.

1) Запятая после "значит" не нужна: основным  является сочинительный союз, в то время как "значит" – конкретизатор значения, паузы нет.

Примеры:

Однако на карту поставлено слишком многое, **а значит** попытаться стоит. [Мария Давыдова. Кто в доме хозяин? (2003) // «100% здоровья», 2003.01.15]

Например, А. Арбатов полагает, что угроза с Запада для нас нулевая, **а значит** на этом направлении не должно быть никаких наших войск [1]. «Отечественные записки», 2003]

2) Конец лета – **не сезон**. Но: конец лета считается **несезоном** (Т.п.), нет отрицания, утвердительное значение слова.

Answer (score 1):

Да, поездку можно сделать (весьма) "**малобюджетной**". "Некультурные" достопримечательности могут быть *природными*. Слово *"исполнить"* навевает ненужные идеи "исполнения бюджета", поездки же *совершают*, а не "исполняют"; урезанное "бюджетный" тоже указывает на принадлежность к какому-то бюджету, хотя в канцелярской практике и может использоваться как упрощение от *малобюджетного* (когда-то и доброкачественное и просто хорошее стало сменяться "качественным", порой вступая в борьбу с "количественным"; в словари это легло, но признаком хорошей речи так и не стало - годится лишь для "отчётов о проделанной работе").

Comment: "Исполнять" - любимое словцо автора; всё рукотворное "исполняется".

Comment: Слово неплохое, но из предложения с мелькающим корнем "бюджет" его лучше перенести, пусть оно мечты или идеи автора исполняет.